# U.S. passport renewal: Do I need a separate check for the 1-2 days delivery fee?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens, passport-renewals

I am applying for US passport renewal. I will use the regular application service (as opposed to the expedited one), so the fee is $110, and I will also choose 1-2 day delivery, which costs $15.89. I wonder if I need to write a single check in the amount of $125.89 or if I need to write two separate checks, one in the amount of $110 and another in the amount of $15.89. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the language implies one check. *Include the delivery service fee with your passport fee in your check*. Implies one check to me because check is singular.

[1-2 Day Delivery Service](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/hurry.html)

> You may choose one or both of the following shipment options:
>
> - Delivery to us: Purchase 1-2 Day Delivery service at a post office or    other passport acceptance facility for faster shipping of your application to us. The price for 1-2 Day Delivery service varies depending on the area of the country.
> - Return to you: Include the $15.89 1-2 Day Delivery service fee with      your passport fee in your check or money order payable to the U.S. Department of State for faster return shipping.

Comment: I would argue that "include the delivery service fee with your passport fee in your check" specifies a single check explicitly rather than implicitly.